# Triggering different click events for a div and an image inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to trigger 2 different click events, 1 for the click on div another when the user clicks on the image. However when the user clicks on the image, the div-click event must be stopped.
I've tried **preventDefault** and **return false** however it did not worked.

```
<div class="col-md-12 m-1 info rounded bg-light hand" id="result1" onclick="show('1')">
Text <b>textssssssss</b><br/> Description <b>desc</b>
<img src="./img/icons/magnify.png" title="Details" style="width: 32px" onclick="window.open('details.php?id=1','_blank');"/>
</div>
```

Comment: [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Geshode the event.stopPropagation() worked.

```
<div class="col-md-12 m-1 info rounded bg-light hand" id="result1" onclick="show('1')">
Text <b>textssssssss</b><br/> Description <b>desc</b>
<img src="./img/icons/magnify.png" title="Details" style="width: 32px" onclick="window.open('details.php?id=1','_blank');event.stopPropagation();"/>
</div>
```